# A function to affect multiple rows to substr and copy with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So, i have this code, it works:

```
var curp = document.getElementById("id_sc_field_curp_id_1");
var getcurp = curp.options[curp.selectedIndex].text;
var rfc = getcurp.substr(0, 10);
document.getElementById("id_sc_field_virtual_rfc_1").value = rfc;
```

It copy the text inside the field (td - CURP) "id_sc_field_curp_id_1", and trim it to put the result in another field (RFC) "id_sc_field_virtual_rfc_1"

[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnfCZ.png)

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/90yzgcqe/1/

I want to adapt the code to work with the other rows, witch have an incremental id...
id_sc_field_curp_id_1,id_sc_field_curp_id_2,id_sc_field_curp_id_3, d_sc_field_virtual_rfc_1, d_sc_field_virtual_rfc_2, d_sc_field_virtual_rfc_3...etc

Im making this function, but... i dont know how to make it work...

```
function rfc() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
var curp = document.getElementById("id_sc_field_curp_id_" + i);
var getcurp = curp.options[curp.selectedIndex].text;
var rfc = getcurp.substr(0, 10);
document.getElementById("id_sc_field_virtual_rfc_" + i).value = rfc;
  }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have html code?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ids? This sounds like the kind of thing where you could just put the same class on each of these and then just grab all of them by their class name and iterate over them

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/90yzgcqe/1/

Comment: my reason is than i'm using scripcase crm, and cant modify html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some jQuery gets us there fairly easily, first get the matching dropdowns and then interact with them.

```
$(function() {
  //get the list of dropdowns that start with all but the numeral
  var lst = $("[id^='id_sc_field_curp_id_']");
  $.each(lst, function(idx, elem) {
    //lets store the dropdown for use in the loop
    let $field = $(elem);
    //for example lets print the selected text
    console.log($field.find("option:selected").text());
  });
});
```

There are a couple of options from there, you can use the dropdown to create the rfc's id, or use the jQuery function `closest()` to get it.  Once you have the associated rfc's input it should be trivial to get set the value.

**EDITED:1**

More specific javascript, and a link to a modified [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90yzgcqe/11/)

```
$(function() {
  //get the list of dropdowns that start with all but the numeral
  var lst = $("[id^='id_sc_field_curp_id_']");
  $.each(lst, function(idx, elem) {
    //lets store the dropdown for use in the loop
    let $field = $(elem);
    //for example lets alert the selected text
    alert($field.find("option:selected").text().substr(0,10));
    $field.closest("[id^='idVertRow']")
        .find("[id^='id_sc_field_virtual_rfc_']")
        .val($field.find("option:selected").text().substr(0,10));
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i'm totally noob to js, do you have and example or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I started by changing yours, but there were too many existing issues.  I will modify it and post the link momentarily

Comment: Thank you Steve, you are a hero!